# Deriving a general rule for power sets

Tags: real-analysis, probability

I am just re-reading some notes, and remembered I couldn't derive a proof for this question.

Define the Power set of any given set, to consist of all the subsets of that set.
Ie the power set of the set A, denoted as P(A) is the set of all subsets of A.

**Question:** Suppose that $A$ is some finite set with $n$ elements. Then show that the power set, $\text{P}(A)$, has $2^n$ elements.

I figured although this is from a real analysis textbook, a result could be obtained using combinatorics, however it escapes me where to begin.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it using induction

Consider the  set $X=\{1\}$ having one element then it has two subsets namely $X$ and $\phi$.thus result is true for $n=1$

Assume the result is true for a set having $n-1$ elements .Then it has $2^{n-1}$ subsets .Let us consider a set having $n$ elements

We can consider the set to be having n-1 elements previously and then adjoining 1 extra element to it

So we already have $2^{n-1}$ subsets and when we adjoin another element we get another $2^{n-1}$ sets together giving $2^n$ sets

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The power set of $A$ is in one-to-one correspondence with the set of sequences taking values in $\{0,1\}$ indexed by $A$, i.e. with the set $$\{(x_a)_{a\in A}~|~x_a\in\{0,1\} \text{ for all }a\in A\}.$$

Can you show this correspondence? Does it help giving your result?